# why my linq query is not giving me expected results

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have this sql query

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime , OutTime)) /60
FROM Attendance
WHERE InTime BETWEEN '01-01-2016' AND '01-31-2016' 
AND Employee=63 

 var AttendofEmp = (from ab in db.Attendances 
                    where ab.InTime >= Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2016") && 
                          ab.InTime >= Convert.ToDateTime("01-31-2016")
                         select new { ab.InTime });
```

it is working fine for sql query,but when I used linq query for getting same results it gives error
          and thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: use new keyword for new instance of datetime . u cannot convert this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `new DateTime()` for your date constants. Additionally, you can use [**`SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.datediffminute(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the minute difference and `.Sum()` to get the sum:

```
var AttendofEmp  =
    (from a in db.Attendances
     where a.InTime >= new DateTime(2016, 1, 4) && a.InTime <= new DateTime(2016, 1, 31)
     select SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute(a.InTime , a.OutTime)
    ).Sum() / 60;
```

Comment: it says SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute does not exists in the current context ,I am new to this...sorry for asking easy questions.I already added namespace System.Data

Comment: Try adding `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient`

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DateDiffMinute(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. I've used the wrong column names.

Comment: I see. Are `InTime` and `OutTime` nullablle columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109225/discussion-between-akash-and-felix-pamittan).

Comment: Yes...both are nullablle columns

Comment: @FelixPamittan You should use DbFunctions.DiffMinutes.

Comment: @akash, as Gert pointed out. Try using `DbFunctions.DiffMinutes`.

Comment: For that I need to upgrade my entity framework...so other function may not work.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Convert `Convert.ToDateTime` to a variable and then use it in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Date1 = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2016");
var Date2 = Convert.ToDateTime("01-31-2016")

     var AttendofEmp = (from ab in db.Attendances 
                        where ab.InTime >= Date1  && 
                              ab.InTime >= Date2 
                             select new { ab.InTime });
```